# GSL multifit solver doesn't update parameters then complains it isn't converging

Tags: c++, c, gsl, least-squares

I'm trying to use the GSL multifit routine to do a fit to some data. The fitting function is a complex numerically-evaluated routine. A simpler version using a Gaussian function works OK, but for my real system, the solver goes through the first iteration, picks a reasonable step, but then fails to update the parameters. Then on the second step it complains that it isn't making progress towards a solution - because it didn't update the parameters!

```
iter:   1 x =    162.76857898  10739059.23031948      1.10107134 |f(x)| = 20.4037
          dx =     -0.25345191 -195704.17835643      0.11771325 
status = iteration is not making progress towards solution
iter:   2 x =    162.76857898  10739059.23031948      1.10107134 |f(x)| = 20.4037
          dx =     -0.00000051     -0.21429092      0.00000018 
chisq/dof = 24.4889
```

Here is the code actually executing the loop:

```
do
{
    iter++;
    status = gsl_multifit_fdfsolver_iterate (solver);

    if(verbose)
    {
        printf ("status = %s\n", gsl_strerror (status));
        print_state (iter, solver);
    }

    // detect an error:
    if (status)
    {
        ret = false;
        break;
    }

    status = gsl_multifit_test_delta (solver->dx, solver->x, 1e-4, 1e-4);
}
while (status == GSL_CONTINUE && iter < 1000);
```

I checked the derivative function and it seems to give a reasonable numerical answer:

```
deriv = 0.14451 , 1.36748e-05 , -0.922072
```

So basically I'm baffled as to why `solver->x` doesn't change between iterations 1 and 2, given that `solver->dx` looks reasonable after iteration 1. Any thoughts?

Edit:
Checking the value of the function after the first iteration:

```
iter:   1 x =    162.76857898  10739059.23031948      1.10107134 |f(x)| = 20.4037
          dx =     -0.25345191 -195704.17835643      0.11771325 
|f(x)| = 20.4037
|f(x+dx)| = 21.512
```

edit 2 changed to actually calculate chi - so that's a problem. Oops...

Comment: can you calculate `|f(x+dx)|`? It might not have updated because it looked like dx was pushing the solver further from the solution.

Comment: Added above...looks fine to me, a decent decrease going to `|f(x+dx)|`

Comment: why do those two values of |f(x)| not match? One is around 20, the other 41.

Comment: Haha yeah I just noticed that, wasn't calculating chi. Just edited, that's the problem. Thanks, will look into what's going on...